# Python multiprocessing on slurm doesn't output print() to console

Tags: python, multiprocessing, slurm

I wrote some data processing script which I wanted to run on our cluster. I use slurm to run it, something like

`srun -c 8 --gres="ht:ht1:8" python -m my_module...`

(gres is some magic due to cluster being gpu-oriented, should not matter in this case.)

Inside my module I have this to handle multiprocessing:

```py
with Pool(processes=num_processes) as pool:
    out = pool.map(
        partial(df_to_stats, **param_dict), frames_uri[0:max_uri_process]
    )
    pool.close()
```

I have fixed dict `param_dict` with params of function which I bake with partial into function for pool.map, and `frames_uri` is my array with data.

Function `df_to_stats` have some prints inside, but I don't see any output in console while running script. At the same time script gives correct results, function return all needed data to `out` variable etc.

To be more specific, prints are bootleg tqdm-like progress bar (because tqdm didn't work like I wanted, that's a whole different issue), but I tested and just `print("test")` doesn't work too

```
    with lock:
        progress[0] += 1
    bar_len = 20
    bar_fill = bar_len * progress[0] // progress[1]
    bar = (
        "█" * bar_fill
        + "_" * (bar_len - bar_fill)
        + " "
        + str(100 * progress[0] // progress[1])
        + "%"
    )
    print("\r" + bar, end="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `slurm` and whatever idiosyncrasies it might have, so I don't know how useful my "answer" will be, especially since you say that doing `print("test")` does not work either. So you may need someone else who is familiar with `slurm` to resolve your more general printing issue. But I do see one problem with your progress bar printing even assuming you can get general printing to display.

First some observations:

You did not post a minimal, reproducible example. Since your problem has to do with printing a progress bar, for this issue you could have used any simple worker function to demonstrate your problem and posted a complete program. You did not do this and so some guesses have to be made.

It appears that your worker function, `df_to_stats`, is trying to rewrite the progress bar. If so, you are trying to print on the same line from multiple pool processes. This approach can work, but it is not the "obvious" solution (at least not to me) and I will present some alternate methods later. Regardless of who is doing the printing, the `print` call that creates the progress bar should specify *flush=True* to force the characters being printed to be output immediately. Without *flush=True* or the printing of a newline character, which I do not see you doing, the output will only be done when a when the program terminates. So first try adding *flush=True* and see if that makes a difference. The following is a minimal, reproducible example using *flush=True*. If your modified code still does not work, then try running the code below and if it works your problem is elsewhere (are you getting an exception prior to printing?):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array, Lock

N_TASKS = 20

lock = Lock()
progress = Array('i', 2)
progress[1] = N_TASKS

def advance_bar():
    with lock:
        progress[0] += 1

    bar_len = 20
    bar_fill = bar_len * progress[0] // progress[1]
    bar = (
        "█" * bar_fill
        + "_" * (bar_len - bar_fill)
        + " "
        + str(100 * progress[0] // progress[1])
        + "%"
    )
    print("\r" + bar, end="", flush=True)  # Do flush=true

def square(x):
    import time

    time.sleep(.2)  # Emulate doing some work
    advance_bar()
    return x * x

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        out = pool.map(square, range(N_TASKS))
        print()  # Add newline to progress bar
        print(out)  # Print results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The other approach would be to have the main process do all the progress bar printing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

N_TASKS = 20

progress = [0, N_TASKS]

def advance_bar(result):
    progress[0] += 1

    bar_len = 20
    bar_fill = bar_len * progress[0] // progress[1]
    bar = (
        "█" * bar_fill
        + "_" * (bar_len - bar_fill)
        + " "
        + str(100 * progress[0] // progress[1])
        + "%"
    )
    print("\r" + bar, end="", flush=True)  # Do flush=true

def square(x):
    import time

    time.sleep(.2)  # Emulate doing some work
    return x * x

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        async_results = [pool.apply_async(square, args=(x,), callback=advance_bar) for x in range(N_TASKS)]
        out = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
        print()  # Add newline to progress bar
        print(out)  # Print results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The only issue with using `apply_async` with a callback is that it is not very efficient when you are submitting many tasks since you do not get the automatic "chunking" that the `map` function provides. Instead you can use the `imap_unordered` method with an explicit *chunksize* value. But since the results are returned in the order that tasks are completed and not in the order in which tasks are submitted (this is what you want for the most accurate progress bar advancement), you will need to explicitly pass the index of the result to and from the worker function:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

N_TASKS = 20

progress = [0, N_TASKS]

def advance_bar():
    progress[0] += 1

    bar_len = 20
    bar_fill = bar_len * progress[0] // progress[1]
    bar = (
        "█" * bar_fill
        + "_" * (bar_len - bar_fill)
        + " "
        + str(100 * progress[0] // progress[1])
        + "%"
    )
    print("\r" + bar, end="", flush=True)  # Do flush=true

def square(tpl):
    import time

    idx, x = tpl  # Unpack
    time.sleep(.2)  # Emulate doing some work
    return idx, x * x  # Return the index along with the result

def main():
    out = [None] * N_TASKS
    with Pool() as pool:
        # For large iterables use something other than chuksize=1:
        for idx, result in pool.imap_unordered(square, enumerate(range(N_TASKS)), chunksize=1):
            out[idx] = result
            advance_bar()
        print()  # Add newline to progress bar
        print(out)  # Print results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! Just using print(... flush=True) helped, my progress bar works just fine now! It worked already without slurm, but slurm is slow with output handling I guess, so flushing made progress bar behave the same as it works at my system. My solution is to have global progress variable and rewrite progress bar using it, and with flushing it works in slurm now.

Comment: Also thanks for info about chunksize, my first solution was using tqdm with imap, but it was 50-100% slower than usual map, apparently it was because default chunksize is 1, setting it to 4 made imap run as fast as usual map. 
Sadly for some reason I can't make tqdm work with slurm. Both tqdm(imap...) and process_map from tqdm.contrib.concurrent output progress bar only when it's finished, and I can't find how to force tqdm flush, so I'll just stick to current progress bar I wrote

Comment: `tqdm` would not work even if you had the main process (see last example using `imap_unordered`) doing all the updating? As an aside, the reason why `imap_unordered` is preferable to `imap` is imaginge if for some crazy reason the first task submitted was the last to complete. With `imap` your bar would not advance at all until all tasks completed and then the progress bar would go instantaneously to 100%. I know this scenario is not likely to happen, but still ...